# How to map a texture around a circle?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I'm using OpenGL to develop a 2D game. and I'm trying to map a texture around a circle, as shown on image below. I have noticed that many games have used this technique because it can save the size of texture resources.

But I don't know which texture mapping technique it used. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like pointed out by genpfault.

Create a bunch of Quads along two circles. Set their UV coordinates A, B, C, D like shown in the picture. To get the point C, just add the distance h to the Vector Center -> B

PS: you will need a lot more quads then i drew

[image: description]

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I need.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a donut of quads with appropriate texture coordinates.